# Pitch calculations

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I am trying to calculate pitch in the X and Y direction for this filter
[BPF-F150+.](https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/BPF-F150+.pdf)

Are the below calculations correct?

N+1/2(D)-1/2(M)
6.99+1.27-1.525 = 265.15mils

Q+1/2(D)-1/2(M)
2.79+1.27-1.525 = 99.80 mils

Thank you

Comment: The X and Y pitches are given on the drawing as dimensions K and L respectively.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany i want to calculate the pitch between horizontal and vertical pads using N and Q values

Comment: @MightyBeard007 I don't know what you mean by "pitch between horizontal and vertical pads", but you are mixing land pattern and package dimensions... this just feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the **bold** dimensions (the package is hard imperial).

I agree with your calculations but I get 0.265" and 0.100"

This kind of thing may be easier to create by setting the origin (at least temporarily) in the center of the package since it is symmetrical.